# Django form not saving if I use action attribute

Tags: python-3.x, django

For context, here is the view.py

```
from .forms import SignIn

...

def sign_in_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = SignIn(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = SignIn(request.POST or None)

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "accounts/sign_in.html", context)
```

here is the HTML file for accounts/sign_in.html

```
{% extends "accounts/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
<title>Log-in</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1 align="center">Sign in</h1>
<hr/>
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/">  # currently in localhost
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Without the attribute action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/" in my form tag in accounts/sign_in.html, I manage to successfully add a user to the database by typing in the required parameters on the browser.

However, with the attribute action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/", I was redirected to the URL, but when I checked the database in /admin/, I was unable to see the user there.

I don't know if the form isn't saved, or I had just done some stupid mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Show also `SignIn` and `urls.py`

Comment: The action url should be the url that process the form not the url it should redirect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action attribute is not for redirection after sending the form. It should be the url attached to the view that is responsible for handling a form. What is the url of your `sign_in_view`? If it is for example `/sign-in/` that should be value of action attribute. If you want to redirect user after signing in, do it in your   `sign_in_view`:

```
 if form.is_valid():
     ...
     return redirect('/home/')
```

Here is a link for Django docs that includes all the useful information about forms:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/

Answer (score 1):

This is a better way for the user to register.

view.py

```
 def sign_in_view(request):
 form = SignIn(request.POST or None)

 if form.is_valid():
     user = form.save()
     username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
     password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

     user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
     
     if user is not None:
         login(request, user)
     return redirect('/')
 
  context = {
    'form': form
}

 return render(request, "accounts/sign_in.html", context)
```

and than in you template you can do this

```
{% extends "accounts/base.html" %}

 {% block title %}
 <title>Log-in</title>
 {% endblock %}

  {% block content %}
    <h1 align="center">Sign in</h1>
  <hr/>
  <form method="POST" action="">  # currently in localhost
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
 </form>
 {% endblock content %}
```